# Exceptions as an error handler OR custom error handling class?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I regularly debate with one of my work colleagues as to the most suitable way of 'doing' error handling within an object orientated PHP project.

He is of the view that we should continue to use Exceptions (legacy code).
In his methodology you would have a method as follows:

`private function doSomething() {
    if (condition) {
        throw new CustomException("error message");
    }
}`

You would then call it within a try catch block and add the exception error to an array of errors (which you can then output as you choose).

In the example above the condition is a boolean comparison for which it is perfectly plausible to receive a true or false response.

Posts like this one: [Error Handling in a PHP Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986476/error-handling-in-a-php-class) seem to agree with this position..

It is my view that because both true or false are perfectly reasonable responses, this is an inappropriate usage of Exceptions. A false is not Exceptional, but rather perfectly normal.

As such I have gone about created a custom error class which you instantiate at the top of your method. Any errors within your method you then add to an errors array property of this instance. You then return this instance back from your method and can call the `passesConditions()` method of the class which returns a boolean dependent on if there are any errors or not.

This approach is always extensible in that you could log all failures in a consistent manner (I appreciate you can do similar with Exceptions :))

So are either of us more correct than the other, and if so why?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think that exception based development is bad, although I'm not completely sure yet.
But I disagree with your statement that 'false and true are both valid results'. Of course that is true for a normal boolean, but in the context of the code you are testing. For instance, if you want to request a file, the file must exist, so FileExists should return true. It could return false, which is valid in itself, but not in the context of this file loader script.
In an other example, you could do an HTTP request and get its result status code as an integer. While 404, 500 and even -1 are perfectly good integers, they indicate an exceptional status, assuming that you expect the url to return a proper 200 OK (or maybe 304 Not modified).

So the fact that you are logging an error to your class, indicates that even you agree it is an erroneous value. Whether you solve that by raising an exception is a completely different discussion.

Personally, I don't like your solution so much. I think it clutters the code, because you always have to process the resulting object (whereas exceptions can be caught on a higher level). Also, if you want to return an actual value from the function as well, the object will be in the way, unless you extend it with an extra property containing the actual result, but then I think you will get lost in your own code really, really soon.